# ldap search filter is not working

Tags: php, search, filter, ldap

I want to get all members of a group.

```
$filter = "member=*";
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, GROUP_USER_ADMINS.",".BASE_DS, $filter);
```

The base_dn is the complete dn of the group.

With this Filter, I get an array with much more informations, what I hadn't planned.

I can use the

```
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
print_r($entries[0][members]);
```

to print the result with only all the members. But why the filter is not working? I want only the members an not all informations about the group like whencreated or the samaccounttype of the group.

Why the filter is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the attributes requested as part of the search request. The default for your API is probably "all user attributes".

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: thanks, it works.
I use the attribute: 
$attr = array("member");
but the result has two arrays with the name "member"
....
[member] => Array

[count] => 2
[0] => some user
[1] => some user

[0] => member
[count] => 1
[dn] => compete dn of the group

is there a way to get only the real member and not the dn member path?

Comment: What do you mean "real member" and not the DN?

Comment: got it.
Note that the "dn" is always returned irrespective of which attributes types are requested.

Answer (score 0):

I added a attribute:
$attr = array('member');
but there are two attributes with a "member" in the name. It is possible to find the attribute only with the real key "member"?

```
Array
(
   [count] => 1
   [0] => Array
   (
      [member] => Array
      (
         [count] => 2
         [0] => CN=User2,OU....,OU=...,DC=...,DC=...
         [1] => CN=User1,OU....,OU=...,DC=...,DC=...
      )

      [0] => member
      [count] => 1
      [dn] => CN=...,OU=....,OU=...,DC=...,DC=...(dn of the group)
   )  
)
```

Comment: `member` is a multi-valued attribute. Multi-valued attributes have multiple values, the only restriction is that all the values must be different (where different means according the matching rule for the attribute)